# Ruby on Rails - possible unmatched constraints: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, gmail, actionmailer

I'm releasing a RoR app running on Heroku and I've been adding all my customers. Everything was ok but there are a few customers that I just can't add because it throws me a 500 error saying: "ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"account_activations", :email=>"customer@customer.com", :id=>nil}, possible unmatched constraints: [:id]):" and I was able to add almost all of them.
What is happening?

Here's my creating clients controller:

```
def create
@client = Client.new(client_params)
if @client.save
  newUser = @client.create_user(name: @client.name,
               email: @client.email,
               password: "PASSWORD",
               password_confirmation: "PASSWORD",
               role:  "client")
  newUser.send_activation_email
  redirect_to root_url
else
  render 'new'
end
end
```

Comment: put your full error trace from the log

Comment: Looks like one of the validations on your `User` model is failing and so the user isn't being saved. What are the validations on `User`?

Comment: @mikej That's what I am realizing... The name validation for the user has a minor length than the customer. Let me see if changing that works.

Comment: `{ ..., :id=>nil }`, the question is how are you making the request to load that template.

Comment: @Aldo Where does the error originate from? **Post the full error, not just the last line.** And why isn't the client saving? Again, post the **full** information -- in this case, the `Client` model and the `client_params`.

Comment: Thank you all! I already solved it and posted the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Found the error. With my client validations I had a name length of 255 while in my user validations I had a length of 50. Some of my customers have names greater than 50 characters. In my controller I just verified with an if statement if client was saved but not the user. The user was failling to be created as @mikej said so I changed the user name validation length also to 255 and now it works.
Thanks!